How to send email saved in notifications table of the database?
When laravel 10 app has value 'database' in via method , as written here
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/notifications
sent emails are saved in notifications table of the database.
There is an artisan command to send these rows as emails - I forgot it and can
not find it this manuals.
Please, remind.

Are they queued?

php artisan queue:work database

I think it is php artisan queue:work.

To send email notifications from the database, I assume those are queued. Here are the steps to dispatch those
Configure queue in the .env
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

Dispatch the queues
php artisan queue:work  // processes the jobs in the queue and then terminates
php artisan queue:listen // listens for every single new job in the queue and processes it as they come in and then terminates

